# How to change the default position of a cursor in a JTextArea?

Tags: java, cursor, jtextarea

I have a `_result` JtextArea. Every second there is a new piece of text `String` being appended to it.
By default, the cursor is at the top.
I need the cursor always to be at the very end of the text in the JTextArea. So that I could see what is the last String being appended.

```
  _result.append("my text");
    // How do I make the cursor of `_result` JTextArea to be at the end of the text?
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this will help.

```
_result.setCaretPosition(_result.getText().length());
```

Comment: use `textField.getDocument().getLength()` which is more efficient then using getText().

Comment: I am sorry, I meant JTextArea, not JTextField. Thank you for your answer. I will try

Comment: I had forgotten about using that method @camickr! Thank You!

Answer (score 1):

There is no `append()` method for a `JTextField`. I assume you are talking about a `JTextArea`.

> By default, the cursor is at the top.

By default the caret should display at the end of the text. If not then you may be doing something wrong. Ccheck out [Text Area Scrolling](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/10/22/text-area-scrolling/) for more information and a couple of solutions.

Answer (score 1):

You could also try:

```
_result.setText(""),
```

then try to append the new text if you only wish to see only the appended text.