# How to change the default cursor position of a JTextArea?

Tags: java, swing, cursor, jtextarea

In [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17768212/how-to-change-the-default-position-of-a-cursor-in-a-jtextarea) I asked how to set cursor to the bottom of the JTextArea. The answer was `textField.getDocument().getLength()`   Technically, I can use `textField.getDocument().getLength()` after every text insert, but this is not convenient.

However, this is not exactly what I meant. I need to change the **JTextArea PROPERTY of cursor position**. In my program `_result` is JTextArea. It gets texts from multiple classes and methods, so using `textField.getDocument().getLength()` everytime after `_result.append("text")` is not convenient and makes code error prone and not flexible

Is there any way I could do something like:

```
// this is just a pseudocode
_result.setDefaultCursorPosition(bottom);
```

and then whenever text goes there (NO MATTER from what class or method), the cursor is always at the bottom.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would move the caret to the end position after each document change:

```
_result.getDocument().addDocumentListener(new DocumentListener() {
        private void atEnd() { 
            _result.setCaretPosition(_result.getText().length()); 
        }
        public void insertUpdate(DocumentEvent evt) { atEnd(); }
        public void removeUpdate(DocumentEvent evt) { atEnd(); }
        public void changedUpdate(DocumentEvent evt) { atEnd(); }
    });
```

It still allows the user to re-position the caret by clicking, or by other calls to `setCaretPosition`.